Gaussian as mixture with uniform weights
Suppose $W$ is $\operatorname{Uniform}[0,1]$ distributed. Suppose $Y|W$ has known mean $\mu(W)$ and variance $\sigma^2(W)$, where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ satisfies some regularity conditions: (1) $\mu$ and $\sigma$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, (2) $\sigma$ is positive over $[0,1]$. Then is it true that there exists some distributions $Y|X$ with given mean and variance such that $Y$ is Gaussian?
I think it is not true in general if $W$ is discrete. For example, if $W \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(\frac{1}{2})$, and $\mu(0) = 0$, $\mu(1) = 1$, $\sigma(0) = \sigma(1) = \delta$ for some small enough $\delta > 0$. Then Markov inequality gives $\mathbb{P}(Y \in [\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}])$ should be very small. However, if $Y$ is Gaussian, it has to be $N(\frac{1}{2},1)$, contradicting the previous point.
Thank you!

You can make your example continuous by defining $W \sim Unif[0,1]$ and $\sigma(x)=\delta$ (small) for all $x \in [0,1]$, and for small $\epsilon>0$ define $$\mu(x) = \left{\begin{array}{cc} 0 & \mbox{ if $x \in [0, 1/2 - \epsilon]$} \ 1 & \mbox{ if $x \in [1/2+\epsilon, 1]$} \end{array}\right.$$ and define $\mu(x)$ continuously on $[1/2-\epsilon,1/2+\epsilon]$.

Thanks, Michael! I think this example would be special in the sense that $\mu$ changes too fast compared to the scale of $\sigma$. In instead, $\mu \in C^p$ and $\sigma \in [m,M]$ for $m$ large enough compared to the derivatives of $\mu$, would it be possible that $Y$ a Gaussian? I think one special case is when $\mu \equiv c$ for some constant $c$, but I'm struggling to find one example of Gaussian $Y$ even in this special case..

For example, $\mu(x) := 0$, $\sigma(x) := \frac{1}{2} + x$, $x \in [0,1]$. Suppose $h_x(t) := \mathbb{P}(Y > t|X = x)$. Then we need $\bar{\Phi}(t) = \int_{0}^1 h_x(t) d x$ for all $t \in [0,1]$, a problem with uncountably infinite constraints but uncountably infinite degree of freedom in choosing $h_x$. Just a bit clueless where to start..

To understand what is possible, it may help to consider examples, for example, let $Y=X+Z$ where $X,Z$ are independent with $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Z\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$. Define $W=F_X(X)$. Then $Y\sim N(0, \sigma^2+1)$, $W \sim Unif[0,1]$. Then $Y|W \sim F_X^{-1}(W) + Z$ which has mean $F_X^{-1}(W)$ and variance $\sigma^2$.
